# OData 404 or 403 on patch

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi

When I updated OData to v4 my patch operations started returning 403 and 404 errors.

My url was in the format

```
curl -X PATCH "http://portal-service/odata/Downloads/553"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using the correct odata format for patch.

```
curl -X PATCH "http://portal-service/odata/Downloads(553)"
```